# How to customize profile pages for external content type search results?

Tags: bcs, external-content-type, enterprise-search

I have set up the SP 2010 enterprise search to include searches in line-of-business data. (In my concrete case that would be data from Dynamics CRM 2011 but I hope that is not relevant). I have defined external content type operations and profile pages. 
However, I want to have a custom design for the rendered search result items. Some sort of branding (e.g. images, typeface, color scheme) should be applied. This is an example of the [standard result item view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDf0M.jpg) that I am speaking of.

How can I customize this design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webparts which display these search results often contain some sort of XML in there edit panel.

1. Set the search result page in Edit Mode
2. edit the webpart which displays the search results and open it's XML-editor under the Show Option tab
3. Copy paste all of that XML into a editor (Visual Studio is what I normally use)
4. Change the branding of the output there and then copy paste it all back to the webpart's XML-editor and apply it.

You'd be interested in editing the Template with name "**SingleResultInternal**" I believe it is.

I hope this helps :)